# Is it better to use Labels instead of Sprites for pop up text

Tags: memory, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, label

I would like to pop up text when the user blasts some balls in my game. At the worst came I may need 70 pop ups at the same time. The pop up is basically the score earned for each ball popped. Right now I am using CCLabel for that. Would it be easier on the processing if I used sprites instead?

I have a lot going on in the game and want to ease the load on the processor.

Advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's no need for 70 popups on an iPhone screen. There's no need for more than 10 popups on an iPhone screen. There's no need for more than 10 popups on any screen of any size. Commence the justifications in 3... 2... *points "You're on!"*

Comment: I'm making a bubble popping game. A pop up comes from every ball popped. Since there can be 70 bubbles on the screen at one time at max, and since there is also a way to pop all of them at the same time, I need 70 pop ups.

Comment: There's a difference between 70 pre-initialized game objects going through a shared texture animation, than 70 pre-initialized game objects plus 70 new objects initialized right before 140 objects go through some visual routine. A large, single "70 combo!" text will do your game justice in every single way that 140 things doing 140 things won't. God forbid you decide to play a sound for each ball popped.

Comment: How is it 140? Are you referring to 70 balls + 70 popups? That is pretty much the worst case. Normally its 3-7 balls popping. And I have decided to do away with labels, I am using BatchNode sprites instead.

Comment: You're missing the larger point. The player will not benefit from each bubble having it's own whatever when it pops/dies/etc. Certainly not something they can read. You're overloading the playing field with useless clutter. That 70+70 is the worst case is not the point, or the worst cast. Your worst case is that you don't see how it degrades usability in your game.

Comment: On that point I disagree. I am not adding it for the heck of it. I am adding it only cuz it adds more life to my game.

Comment: You're confusing "life" with clutter. But, it's your game and your right to approach it wrong.

Comment: I think it is you who is confusing clutter with life. What you see as clutter I see as something that adds to my game in a positive way. If you can't help with my programming question, that's fine. I respect your opinion of calling my approach wrong, but I disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CCLabelBMFont, you shouldn't see much difference between that and using a Sprite.  Using CCLabel would probably be a mistake and may present a noticeable difference between CCLabelBMFont and CCSprite.

Comment: I am using CCLabelTTF. Is that ok?

Comment: So for this situation would you recommend using Sprites?

Comment: I wouldn't use CCLabelTTF, if you have a bunch of different numbers that you plan on showing (i.e. 10 pts, 25, 30, 50) then I'd just use CCLabelBMFont.

Comment: @Abhinav you should mark questions as answered, to improve the community and help people who stumble across this.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. I am not completely familiar with StackOverflow yet. Thanks.